# excluding proceeding char using regex_substr

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-negation

How do i use oracle regexp_substr to receive a portion of a string that is proceeded with @.

I have the string

```
sip:+1111@aaa.123.text
```

I want to get the numeric part (`1111` in this example) that is between the + and proceeded by @. I got as far as

```
regexp_substr(str, '\+.*@')
```

But I cannot omit the @ character.

Comment: @Avinash Raj too bad Oracle has not implemented lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an Oracle 11g (or greater) database, you just need to use the sub-expression parameter as follows:

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT 'sip:+1111@aaa.123.text' c_str FROM dual
  )
SELECT regexp_substr(c_str, '\+(\d*)@',1,1, NULL, 1) FROM t
```

**Explanation of matching pattern:**

1. Escape the plus character, `+`.
2. Use a character grouping for the repeating digit, `(\d*)`.  Specifically, this character grouping is looking for a repeating digit, `\d`, pattern with a quantifier of `*`, meaning 0 or more matches. The character grouping is identified by encapsulating the desired group in parenthesis, `()`.

**Other parameters explained:**

```
1, 1, NULL, 1
```

These parameters state that I am starting at the beginning position of the string and looking for the 1st occurrence. I set the match parameter to NULL.

Finally, the last parameter, 1, is the 11g feature where I can indicate the matching sub-expression.  Since I only use one sub-expression in my matching pattern, thus I pass the number, 1.

You can find more examples of this sub-expression referencing in the Oracle 11g [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm).